# Creating function to filter and calculate division of rows based on filter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, function, data-science

I have a df such as below:

I am using simple code such as below: that filters columns in the **df** and then I calculate simple math based on value of the column,
so if the column values is cancelled, processing, and complete; I want to calculate the % or number of rows that were cancelled of the entire df or all the rows.

df looks like:

```
   ID |    Status    |   Color
   555    Cancelled     Green
   434    Processed     Red   
   212    Cancelled     Blue
   121    Cancelled     Green
   242    Cancelled     Blue
   352    Processed     Green
   343    Processed     Blue
```

The Code Im currently using is:

```
df[df['Color'] == 'Green']

df[(df['Status']=='Cancelled') & (df['Color']=='Green')]
```

Meaning for each different type of color I manually first filter the df to get the # of rows, then double filter it below to get the number of rows or orders cancelled then manually divide that # but he # of just green rows.

If I wanted to create a function where I can insert the color name and the status and do the math that way in a simple function what would be the best approach for that?

Expected Output would be something like:

```
 Status      Green
Cancelled    0.666667
Processed    0.333333
dtype: float64
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use groupby and len():

```
df.groupby(by='Status').apply(lambda x: len(x)/len(df))

Status
Cancelled    0.666667
Processed    0.333333
dtype: float64
```

Breakdown by both Status and Color:

```
cc = df.groupby(by='Color').ID.count()
df.groupby(by=['Color', 'Status']).apply(lambda x: len(x)/cc.loc[x.Color.iloc[0]])

Color  Status   
Blue   Cancelled    0.666667
       Processed    0.333333
Green  Cancelled    0.666667
       Processed    0.333333
Red    Processed    1.000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks, but I wanted to also filter by the color column

Comment: can you give your expected output?

Comment: expected output is added just like your answer, except it would be for a certain color I could pick instead of the overall df

Comment: The expected output doesn't quite make sense to me. Where are the other colors and there is no processed for Green but why do you put 0.333 for Green-Processed?

Comment: I gave a sample of the data, meaning there are a lot of other rows in the df I updated the sample dataset, sorry!

Comment: No worries. How would you handle other colors? Can you give a minimal and complete input and output example?